# Parsing data from textbox into multiple textboxes - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to paste the tab-delimited data (shown below) into a multi-line text box.

**Data**:

```
Fat 119.3g  62.1%
Saturated Fat   26.4g   
Cholesterol 442.5mg 
Sodium  3,824.8mg   
Carbohydrates   80.1g   18.5%
Fiber   12.1g   
Sugars  26.6g   
Protein 83.7g   19.4%
```

**NOTE**: Each row is: *[nutrient name][tab][g/mg amount][tab][% (only on 3)]*

When I click a button, I would like the following to happen:

```
fatInput.text = "119.3"
satfatInput.text = "26.4"
cholesteralInput.text = "442.5"
sodiumInput.text = "3824.8"
carbInput.text = "80.1"
fiberInput.text = "12.1"
sugarInput.text = "26.6"
proteinInput.text = "83.7"
```

So to summarize, it pulls those numbers out of the textbox I pasted it into and enters them into the separate textboxes. Commas, "g" and "mg" should not be included. The three percentages are not relevant and may be ignored. The nutrient names, order, and tabs do not change.

Is this even possible?!

THANKS FOR THE HELP!!!

**Disclaimer**: Not a programmer, just have basic knowledge and thought of a fun program to make to help me track what I eat. I've completed the program but decided to enhance  it with the below so I don't have to manually type in these numbers. If this is too complicated I don't need the answer, just some direction and I can figure it out. I have no clue where to start!

Comment: UI Controls make horrible variables.  Do this originate from some file?

Comment: It's actually from a website which is why I'd like to copy/paste it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The TextBox has a [Lines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property giving you access to the text lines entered.

Then you can split the line further with the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
Dim parts() As String = line.Split(ControlChars.Tab)
```

VB has handy [Val](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function that gets a number contained in a string. but it does not handle the comma, so remove it using the [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function before getting the number

```
Dim d As Double = Val(parts(1).Replace(",", ""))
```

Then you can get the unit by looking at the two right most characters using the [Right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxs6hz0a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function and see whether it is "mg", if not check the right most character to see if it is a "g".

Comment: Thank you this makes sense to me so far, I will give it a try tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Olivier for getting my brain thinking in the right order:

1. use Lines property to put it an an array
2. grab a single line from the array
3. grab only numbers from the line (I used an if/then statement since Val kept returning "0")
4. cut it off at "g" or "mg" (which was easy since I already had an if/then statement)
5. repeat for each of the 8 lines

Probably nasty, but here's the code I used:

```
    Dim msgStr As String
    Dim newStr As String = ""
    Dim tempArray() As String
    tempArray = pasteInput.Lines
    msgStr = (tempArray(0))
    For Each value As Char In msgStr
        If value >= "0" And value <= "9" Or value = "." Then
            newStr &= value
        ElseIf value = "g" Or value = "mg" Then
            fatInput.Text = newStr
            newStr = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    msgStr = (tempArray(1))
    For Each value As Char In msgStr
        If value >= "0" And value <= "9" Or value = "." Then
            newStr &= value
        ElseIf value = "g" Or value = "mg" Then
            satfatInput.Text = newStr
            newStr = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    msgStr = (tempArray(2))
    For Each value As Char In msgStr
        If value >= "0" And value <= "9" Or value = "." Then
            newStr &= value
        ElseIf value = "g" Or value = "mg" Then
            cholInput.Text = newStr
            newStr = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    msgStr = (tempArray(3))
    For Each value As Char In msgStr
        If value >= "0" And value <= "9" Or value = "." Then
            newStr &= value
        ElseIf value = "g" Or value = "mg" Then
            sodiumInput.Text = newStr
            newStr = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    msgStr = (tempArray(4))
    For Each value As Char In msgStr
        If value >= "0" And value <= "9" Or value = "." Then
            newStr &= value
        ElseIf value = "g" Or value = "mg" Then
            carbInput.Text = newStr
            newStr = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    msgStr = (tempArray(5))
    For Each value As Char In msgStr
        If value >= "0" And value <= "9" Or value = "." Then
            newStr &= value
        ElseIf value = "g" Or value = "mg" Then
            fiberInput.Text = newStr
            newStr = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    msgStr = (tempArray(6))
    msgStr = Replace(msgStr, "Sugars", "")
    For Each value As Char In msgStr
        If value >= "0" And value <= "9" Or value = "." Then
            newStr &= value
        ElseIf value = "g" Or value = "mg" Then
            sugarInput.Text = newStr
            newStr = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    msgStr = (tempArray(7))
    For Each value As Char In msgStr
        If value >= "0" And value <= "9" Or value = "." Then
            newStr &= value
        ElseIf value = "g" Or value = "mg" Then
            proteinInput.Text = newStr
            newStr = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```